# Getting multiple characters when using Scanner next() method in Java?

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert infix arithmetic expressions to postfix expressions using a stack.  I'm using the `scanner.next()` method to scan through the string expression and essentially split it up and use a `switch-case` block to check which operation is being performed.

However, the `scanner.next()` method attaches parentheses to any numbers.  For example, (5 + 5) will not be read as a '(' '5' '+' etc. but will be read as "(5" "+" "5)" so the case for the ')' is being totally skipped because there is always a number attached to the front of it.  is there a way I can separate the parentheses from the numbers?

This is my code:

```
while(in.hasNext())
    {
        String expr = in.next();
        op = expr.charAt(0);

        //testing the ops
        System.out.println("OP IS: "+ expr + " ");

        switch(expr)
        {
            case "+":
            case "-":
                while(!stack.isEmpty() && !stack.peek().equals("("))
                {
                    postfixStr = postfixStr.concat("" + stack.pop() + " ");
                }
                stack.push(expr);
                break;

            case "*":
            case "/":
                while(!stack.isEmpty() && !stack.peek().equals("(") && !stack.peek().equals("+") && !stack.peek().equals("-"))
                {
                    postfixStr = postfixStr.concat("" + stack.pop() + " ");
                }
                stack.push(expr);
                break;

            case "(":
                stack.push(expr);
                System.out.println("IT HAS BEEN PUSHED");
                break;

            case ")":
                System.out.println("TEST POINT 1");
                String peekOp = stack.peek();
                while(!stack.isEmpty() && !peekOp.equals("("))
                {
                    postfixStr = postfixStr.concat("" + stack.pop() + " ");
                    System.out.println("%%%%" + peekOp);
                    peekOp = stack.peek();

                }
                System.out.println("TEST POINT 2");
                stack.pop();

                break;

            default:
                postfixStr = postfixStr.concat("" + expr + " ");
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code creates an infinite loop also.

Comment: to keep it concise, i left out most of the code.  this is just the part that is causing the problem.

Comment: I just gave you the hint that your while loop will create infinite loop if you are taking input from user in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the javadocs for java.util.Scanner at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html, you can use any custom expression to be used as delimiter, (space is considered the default, hence your entry with parenthesis was taken as one string).

Following is the excerpt from javadocs.

The scanner can also use delimiters other than whitespace. This example reads several items in from a string. You can use parentheses as the delimiter in your case.

```
String input = "1 fish 2 fish red fish blue fish";
 Scanner s = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("\\s*fish\\s*");
 System.out.println(s.nextInt());
 System.out.println(s.nextInt());
 System.out.println(s.next());
 System.out.println(s.next());
 s.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't just assume you're getting the first character; loop through all characters no matter how many you get from `.next()`. Try this:

```
while(in.hasNext())
{
    String expr = in.next();

    for (int i = 0; i < expr.length(); i++){
        char op = expr.charAt(i); 

        // ... the rest of your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: oo. I can see this working, but my default case might cause problems because if there is an integer, for example 352, it would put spaces between each number so it would look like 3 5 2.

Comment: True. Any number longer than 1 digit would be split up. Also my answer is a bit of a hack - the best thing would probably be to set custom options for the Scanner as the other answers mentioned. Or better yet, just read the whole String at once (if possible) and then loop through char-by-char like my example.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Scanner Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).  It defaults to skip whitespace, so you can either mandate white space around any token, including parenthesis, or you may use another kind of tokenizer that will return the tokens for you.

I found [JFLex](http://jflex.de/) worth the learning curve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code. You need to iterate charArray and process it..

```
char op;
char[] charArray;
while(in.hasNext()) {
    String expr = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Expression IS: "+ expr + " ");
    charArray = expr.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("OP IS: "+ charArray[i] + " ");
        switch(charArray[i]) {
            // your switch code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanner is just tricky to do that. You need something powerful as Regular Expression, fortunately I have the right expressión, with little modifications this sample based in your code works perfectly:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class RegexSample {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        char op;
        String expression = "(5+2 )/ 3 - 1 * abc123-(( (123/ 123) )-1) - 1 + 2";

        // equivalent to the regular expression \+|\-\*|\/|\(|\)|\w
        // that accepts + , - , * , / , 
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\+|\\-|\\*|\\/|\\(|\\)|\\w+");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(expression);

        System.out.println("start - " + expression);


        while ( m.find() ) {
            String expr = m.group();
            op = expr.charAt(0);

            //testing the ops
            System.out.println("OP IS: " + expr + " ");


            switch (expr) {
                // your switch code

            }

        }

    }
}
```